# What is the difference between "I learned to drive in 6 months" & "I learned to drive for 6 months"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I would say  "**I learned to drive in 6 months**" emphasize how long it took to learn to drive & "**I learned to drive for 6 months**" emphasize how long it lasted and the continuity of the action.

Here are some of my studies:

In [some dictionaries](http://thefreedictionary.com/in), they say

> You use **in** to say how long something takes.
>
> He learned to drive in six months.
>
> The food was all eaten in a few minutes.
>
> Be Careful!
>
> Don't say that something lasts or continues 'in' a period of time. Say that it lasts or continues **for** that time.
>
> I have known you for a long time.
>
> I worked for the same company for ten years.

But in other [dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/in_1?q=in), they see "**in**" as "**after a particular length of time**" not "**how long it takes**"

> in: **after a particular length of time**
>
> to return in a few minutes/hours/days/months.
>
> It will be ready in a week's time (= one week from now).
>
> She learnt to drive in three weeks (= after three weeks she could
>   drive).

But [other dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time) distinguish "**in**" when to say when something will happen & when to say how long someone takes to do something

> We use **in** to say how long it takes someone to do something:
>
> He was such a clever musician. He could learn a song in about five minutes.
>
> We use an apostrophe -s construction (in a year’s time, in two months’
>   time) to say when something will happen. We don’t use it to say how
>   long someone takes to do something:
>
> I won’t say goodbye because we’ll be seeing each other again in three
>   days’ time. We can also say in three days, without time, in this
>   example.
>
> He ran the marathon in six hours and 20 minutes.

Comment: Excellent research on the meaning and usage of **in**, but what happened with **for**?

Comment: I think the contrast is clearer between   "I learned German in 6 days" and  "I learned German  for 6 days".  In the first case, it seems I am clever and German is easy, and now I can speak German.  In the second, I went to classes but perhaps I am too stupid and German is too difficult so I stopped

Comment: @Mari-LouA, "**for**" is so obvious. That is it expresses how long something lasts. That is why I don't mention "**for**" a lot!

Comment: They're such different ideas, they shouldn't be compared. *I learned to drive for six months* is simply inappropriate.

If you want to put it that way, you need *I studied driving for six months*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I learned to drive **in** six months

It took the speaker six months to learn "how" to drive.
**Result**: Today, the speaker knows how to drive, and I would understand that he or she passed their driver's test.

> 2. I learned to drive **for** six months

At a specific moment in the past, someone taught the speaker how to drive for six months but for an undisclosed reason, the speaker either stopped learning or stopped driving.
**Result**: The sentence implies that the speaker does not drive today or stopped learning to drive.

Comment: Yes. The essential difference between using "in" and using "for" in this context is that "in" suggests the thing has been completed. I am not sure it always means "satisfactorily completed", otherwise why would we say "His ability at playing tennis is that of someone who learned in a weekend".

Comment: I think "I was learning to drive for 6 months." is more correct for #2.  The progressive form of the verb indicates the action's end wasn't yet reached.  I feel like "I learned to drive for 6 months." is not gramamtically correct.  But yes, the "for" indicates the action wasn't really completed as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with "I learned to drive for 6 months" is that it's likely to be parsed as "I learned to (drive for 6 months)" rather than "I (learned to drive) for 6 months". It would be more natural to use different wording, such as "I took driving lessons for six months."

Answer (score 0):

- I learned to drive in 6 months.
- ** I learned to drive for 6 months.
- ** I was learning to drive in 6 months.
- I was learning to drive for 6 months.
- ** I practiced driving in 6 months.
- I practiced driving for 6 months.

I put **s by the invalid sentences above.  Now an explanation:

With "I learned to drive in 6 months" the "in 6 month" indicates a point in time (somewhere in 6 months).  With "I learned to drive for 6 months the "for 6 months" indicates an interval of time.

The act of learning to drive has duration followed by a change of state.  "I learned to drive" is talking about the change of state, so its compatible with a point of time (in 6 months) but not an interval (for 6 months).

You could change things to not involve a change of state so it works with an interval by using the past progressive form (which then indicates the learning may not have completed).

- I was learning to drive for 6 months.

Note that "I was learning to drive in 6 months." is wrong, the state change that would fit the point in time is no longer available to fit the "in 6 months"

You could also choose an action that doesn't involve a state change by using practice instead of learn.  With that change its compatible with the interval, but not the point in time.